# How to create two ByteStrings calling this external library API?

Tags: haskell, ffi, bytestring

I'm currently writing bindings to a cryptographic library that exposes a function for generating keypairs:

```
const size_t PUBLICKEYBYTES = 32;
const size_t SECRETKEYBYTES = 32;
int random_keypair(unsigned char pk[PUBLICKEYBYTES],
                   unsigned char sk[SECRETKEYBYTES]);
```

This function randomly generates a secret key, computes the corresponding public key and puts the results in `pk` and `sk`.

When just returning one `ByteString` I've found that the easiest way is to use `create :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> IO ByteString` from `Data.ByteString.Internal`. However, that function can't create two `ByteStrings` at the same time.

My first approach was to write something like:

```
newtype PublicKey = PublicKey ByteString
newtype SecretKey = SecretKey ByteString
randomKeypair :: IO (PublicKey, SecretKey)
randomKeypair = do
    let pk = B.replicate 0 publicKeyBytes
        sk = B.replicate 0 secretKeyBytes
    B.unsafeUseAsCString pk $ \ppk ->
        B.unsafeUseAsCString sk $ \psk ->
        c_random_keypair ppk psk
    return (PublicKey pk, SecretKey sk)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with GHC 7.10.2. When running the test suite I'm finding that I seem to have sharing of the `ByteString`s in between function calls, leading to encryption/decryption failing and giving incorrect results.

I've managed to work around the problem by defining my own function:

```
createWithResult :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO a) -> IO (ByteString, a)
createWithResult i f = do
    fp <- B.mallocByteString i
    r <- withForeignPtr fp f
    return (B.fromForeignPtr fp 0 i, r)
```

and using it like:

```
randomKeypair = fmap (PublicKey *** SecretKey) $
    createWithResult publicKeyBytes $ \ppk ->
    B.create secretKeyBytes $ \psk ->
    void $ c_random_keypair ppk psk
```

This seems to work, all tests pass.

My question is, what exactly are the semantics when it comes to sharing and referential transparency when it comes to the `IO` monad?

My intuition told me (incorrectly) that I could solve the problem in the first way, but apparently I couldn't. What I believe was happening is that the optimizer saw that the `let`-statements could be floated up into top level definitions, and that was the reason I got these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first approach is that you're trying to modify an immutable value (`pk` and `sk` in your function). The [docs for unsafeUseAsCString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeUseAsCString) say:

> modifying the CString, either in C, or using poke, will cause the contents of the ByteString to change, breaking referential transparency

The `IO` monad doesn't have different semantics when it comes to sharing and referential transparency. In fact, the `let` in the `do` block is not in any way related to `IO` monad; your code is equivalent to:

```
randomKeypair :: IO (PublicKey, SecretKey)
randomKeypair =
    let pk = B.replicate 0 publicKeyBytes
        sk = B.replicate 0 secretKeyBytes
    in B.unsafeUseAsCString pk (\ppk ->
        B.unsafeUseAsCString sk $ \psk ->
        c_random_keypair ppk psk) >>
    return (PublicKey pk, SecretKey sk)
```

Now it's clearly visible that `pk` and `sk` can be floated to top level.

Comment: So if ByteString had exposed a 'replicateIO :: Int -> Word8 -> IO ByteString' function that didn't call 'unsafePerformIO', then it would have worked?

Answer (score 4):

This does not answer your question, but it's too long to be put in a comment.

As a hack, if you want to avoid doing manual allocations, you could use two nested `create` calls and an `IORef ByteString` to store the bytestring created by the innermost `create`. E.g. (pseudocode)

```
secRef <- newIORef ""
pubB <- create publicKeyBytes (\pub -> do
   secB <- create secretKeyBytes (\sec -> void $ c_random_keypair pub sec)
   writeIORef secRef secB)
secB <- readIORef secRef
return (pubB, secB)
```

However, I prefer your `createWithResult` to this approach.