# Haskell FFI: Correct way to pass in and return ByteStrings

Tags: c, haskell, garbage-collection, ffi, bytestring

**Setup**

Suppose you have a typical C API where some struct is allocated, then initialised (memory allocated, handles created, etc.), then worked upon (transformed, queried, etc.) using various functions, and finally freed again. I.e. the standard C-style OO framework where the struct is the 'object' and the functions are the 'member functions'.

More specifically, let the API work on bytestrings. For example, this could be a compression library.

In Haskell, `Data.ByteString.ByteString`, at the lowest level, is just "pinned memory in the GC heap" (allocated with [`mallocPlainForeignPtrBytes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Internal.html#mallocByteString)), the pointer to which is the first argument to the `ByteString` constructor [`PS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Internal.html#PS). The underlying memory of the `ByteString` can be obtained with [`Data.ByteString.Internal.toForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9/docs/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#v%3AtoForeignPtr). So far so good.

**Passing down `ByteString`**

It is convenient to let Haskell manage the `ByteString` on which the C API operates. In C we might have a struct and a init function like this:

```
   typedef struct { 
       uint8_t* buf; 
       size_t buflen; 
   } API_t;

   void API_init_as_writer(API_t* p, uint8_t* buf, size_t buflen);
```

`buf` and `buflen` hold the Haskell `ByteString`. This object becomes a 'writer'. The Haskell binding would look like this:

```
   data API  -- empty decl (needs EmptyDataDecls extension)

   foreign import ccall unsafe "API.h API_init_as_writer"
       init :: Ptr API -> Ptr Word8 -> Int -> IO ()
```

where the `Ptr Word8` is obtained with [`toForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9/docs/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#v:toForeignPtr) and [`withForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:withForeignPtr).

**Returning (passing up) a `ByteString`**

Similarly, we can let the object (struct) become a 'reader' and create the `ByteString` as described above, using `mallocPlainForeignPtrBytes` and `PS`.

**Garbage collection gets in the way!**

The trouble with this is that the garbage collector does not know that the `ByteStrings` are being used (via the struct that holds the pointer to the memory on the GC heap) after the API_init_* functions have been called. In the case of the 'writer':

```
    writer <- initWriter 1024     -- inits with buflen of 1024 via mallocPlainForeignPtrBytes
    writeSomething writer
    writeSomethingElse writer
    ...
    bs <- getByteString writer    -- construct ByteString with PS
    writeFile "Some.file" bs
```

and in the case of the 'reader':

```
    bs <- ByteString.readFile("Some.file")
    reader <- initReader bs
    info1 <- readSomething reader
    info2 <- readSomethingElse reader
```

All this happens in the IO monad.

Clearly, this doesn't work. The `ByteString` may get garbage collected after `initWriter` or `initReader`, and the `writeSomething` or `readSomething` functions will continue using the garbage collected memory.

And, notwithstanding any GC issues, just like the `ByteString` has been "unsafe'd" out of the IO monad, these API `ByteString` ops shouldn't be in the IO monad, either, because there isn't really any IO or interaction with `RealWorld` happening.

So the question is: **How is this structured correctly in Haskell?**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197977/how-to-create-two-bytestrings-calling-this-external-library-api/32198466#32198466) SO question leads to the hint of using `IORef`, which is not very nice.

My hunch is that this needs to be made functional. The sequential nature of these OO-type APIs (alloc, init, operate, operate, ..., free) necessitate the introduction of a monad other than the IO monad, I guess. But I don't quite see how to set this up correctly. When I look at database bindings I only see the IO monad. For example, the [`db_get`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/BerkeleyDB-0.8.7/docs/Database-Berkeley-Db.html#v:db_get) function of the [BerkeleyDB binding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/BerkeleyDB-0.8.7/docs/Database-Berkeley-Db.html) returns a `IO (Maybe ByteString)` - the GC problem doesn't arise because the `ByteString` is the result of the query. I'm a bit puzzled right now. I guess I'm hitting the friction point between OO and FP. Or maybe I'm looking at this completely in the wrong way.

**Update 1**

As @Alec points out, the GC problems can be alleviated (solved?) by using the [`touchForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:touchForeignPtr). I still have a strong inclination to take this out of the IO monad, though, towards a cleaner interface.

Comment: You can force the `ByteString` to not be GC'ed via `touchForeignPtr`. That doesn't solve all of your problems, but it sure helps the examples you gave. You'll have to tiptoe around laziness though...

Comment: touchForeignPtr: "This function ensures that the foreign object in question is alive at the given place in the sequence of IO actions." That's neat.

Comment: Regarding wanting to avoid `IO` in favour of another monad, you could go to `ST`. Depending on what you are doing `unsafeIOToST :: IO a -> ST s a` might be useful for lifting an FFI imported `IO` action to `ST`.

Comment: `unsafeIOToST` is a nice mechanism. One drawback I noticed is that `liftIO` is not avaliable in `ST`. In `ST` that makes sense, but since my `ST` ist just `IO` in disguise, `liftIO` ought to be available. I guess it's possible to make my own `myLiftIO`, which is actually just `unsafeIOToST`, I think.